# How to use array.reduce() with react hook useState, useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, reduce, react-hooks

Edit: Please find my whole component code down below. No "data" state refreshed on useEffect ... What's the heck !!!

I get data from firebase in useEffect. In useEffect, I store my data( which is an array) in a state using useState. 
I want to use this data in my rfc render method but first need to reduce() it. 
I tried to reduce it in original useEffect (the same where I am fetching the data), in a other useEffect, or even in my render method. None of these could actually make it. My accumulator argument stays empty in my reduce function. 
Please, I really need some help on this.

```
 import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Grid, Paper, Typography, Table, TableBody, TableCell, TableHead, TableRow } from '@material-ui/core'
import firebase from './../firebase'

const db = firebase.firestore()

export default function Scores(props) {

    let { match } = props
    let [currentEvent, setcurrentEvent] = useState(null)
    let [records, setRecords] = useState([])
    let [data, setdata] = useState(null)




    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("effet 1")
        db.collection('events').doc(match.params.id)
          .onSnapshot(doc => {

            setcurrentEvent(currentEvent = { ...doc.data(), uid: doc.id })
            setRecords(records = doc.data().records)
          })

      }, [])

      useEffect(() => {
            console.log(records)
          let x = records.reduce((result, record) => {
              console.log(record)
            result[record.user] = result[record.user] || []
            result[record.user].push(record.time.seconds)
            console.log(result)
            return result
        }, [])
          console.log(x)
          setdata(data = x)

      }, [records])






      if (!currentEvent) {
          return (<h1>data loading ...</h1>)
      }

      return (
          <Paper style={{margin: 8, padding: 8}}>
              <Typography variant='h4'>
                {data.length}
              </Typography>

              <Typography>

              </Typography>


              <Table >
                <TableHead>
                    <TableRow>
                        <TableCell>Participant</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">run 1</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">run 2</TableCell>
                        <TableCell align="right">run 3</TableCell>

                    </TableRow>
                </TableHead>
                <TableBody>


                </TableBody>
            </Table>

          </Paper>
      )




}



/*
useEffect(() => {
          console.log("hi")
          console.log(records)
        let data = records.reduce((result, record) => {
            result[record.user] = result[record.user] || []
            result[record.user].push(record.time.seconds)
            console.log('coucou')
            return result
        }, [])
        setRecords(records = 'coucou')
      }, [])

*/
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're handling everything inside of a return function, with `useEffect` that works similar to a `componentWillUnmount` - as explained in the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Try to run your `reduce` logic before the return function:

```
useEffect(() => {
    let records = [];
    let x = records.reduce((result, record) => {
      result[record.user] = result[record.user] || []
      result[record.user].push(record.time.seconds)
      return result
  }, [])
  setdata(data = x)
  }, [records])
```

Comment: Hum... If you start 'records' being an empty array, How do you want it to do anything ? I think the return function as nothing to do with that...

Comment: I think that my manipulation over the array is right. The problem is about the state not updating. And I don't know why. I can setdata to a simple variable and it works good, but as soon as I use reduce(), something strange is happening....

Comment: I think no render method is call afterwards. But useState is called in useEffect, so render should fire !!!

Comment: We're talking about the wrong return function, the return you are calling at the top of useEffect is making it so your useEffect does nothing when it mounts

Comment: All of your logic is only being called on unmount

Answer (score 1):

```
setdata(data = x)
```

This is not how you should be using the `useState` hook. In this line you're trying to assign a value to your state variable as an argument to your state update function.

It should look like this `setdata(x)`

[More info here ...](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html#declaring-a-state-variable)

Check your dev tools for errors (TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.).